# Interleave list of list without modules

Tags: python

Suppose you have the following list of lists:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], 
         [9, 0], 
         [5], 
         [-4,-5,-2,-3,-1]];
```

Using only basic operations and loops, how to interleave the lists, so the result is the following:

```
result = [1,9,5,-4,2,0,-5,3,-2,-3,-1]
```

All the solutions I found here use some sort of libraries, but I'm interested in the solution only using loops.

My current solution is:

```
result = []

def interleave(myList):
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if len(myList[i]) == 0:
            continue
        result.append( myList[i][0] )
        del myList[i][0]
    print result

list1 = [[1,2,3], [9, 0], [5], [-4,-5,-2,-3,-1]]
print list1

interleave(list1)
interleave(list1)
interleave(list1)
interleave(list1)
interleave(list1)
```

What tricks me right now, is how to put these 5 calls to my `interleave` function inside the function, so I call `interleave()` only once.

Comment: Post the code that you have so far and explain where you are stuck specifically.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you -- help us to understand where you're stuck or what methods you've considered, and this will be answerable.

Comment: Now you should explain what exactly is wrong with your current solution and why it confuses you.

Comment: @AdamSmith this is not a homework. I'm practicing code and I'm trying to understand basic algo. Anyway, i edited the question with my current code

Comment: good catch. I will edit the question

Comment: @AdhySatya a minor nitpick: that just makes it homework you gave yourself ;) Regardless this is fairly answerable now -- follow csmckelvey's advice and it's actually a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a good option to use a generator. A simple algorithm would be create a list of iterators and consume one item from each iterator, and remove the iterator if it is empty:

```
def interleave(l):
    q = [iter(i) for i in l]
    while q:
        n = q.pop(0)
        try:
            yield next(n)
            q.append(n)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

In []:
list(interleave(list1))

Out[]:
[1, 9, 5, -4, 2, 0, -5, 3, -2, -3, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],
         [9, 0], 
         [5], 
         [-4,-5,-2,-3,-1]]

list2 = []

flag = True
while flag:
  for elem in list1:
    if not elem:
      flag = False
    else:
      list2.append(elem.pop(0))
      flag = True




print(list2)
```

Results in :

```
[1, 9, 5, -4, 2, 0, -5, 3, -2, -3, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be the following: First, find the sublist with the biggest length. Then for the range of numbers in that length (that is, the indices of the sublist with the biggest length), loop through every sublist and check if the current number of the range is smaller than its length (which means that it is OK to take index without risking `IndexError`), take that number and store it on the new list. Below is the code demonstrating my thought:

```
def interleave(inList):
    maximumLength = len(max(inList, key=len))
    return [elem[i] for i in range(maximumLength) for elem in list1 if i < len(elem)]

list1 = [[1,2,3], [9, 0], [5], [-4,-5,-2,-3,-1]]

print(interleave(list1))
```

Output:

```
[1, 9, 5, -4, 2, 0, -5, 3, -2, -3, -1]
```